# Add a png image to a imagelist in runtime using Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need add in runtime a png image to a `TImageList`. I've looked at the functions implemented by the `TCustomImageList` but they only allow adding

- bitmaps,
- icons or
- images from another imagelist

E.g.:

```
function Add(Image, Mask: TBitmap): Integer;
function AddIcon(Image: TIcon): Integer;
function AddImage(Value: TCustomImageList; Index: Integer): Integer;
procedure AddImages(Value: TCustomImageList);
function AddMasked(Image: TBitmap; MaskColor: TColor): Integer;
```

How I can add a PNG image to a ImageList component without converting this image to BMP?

The IDE already can add a PNG to an ImageList at design time:

[image]

Now we need to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN an imagelist can only contain bitmaps and icons. To add a png image to an imagelist you have to convert it to an icon first. The code to do that can be found in the [PngComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127) package. If you have only PNG images in your imagelist you can for simplicity just use TPngImageList that comes with that package.

Answer (score 23):

Delphi XE has all the support to handle png images and 32-bit
bitmaps with alpha channel. Here is how to add png to an ImageList:

```
uses CommCtrl;

var pngbmp: TPngImage;
    bmp: TBitmap;
    ImageList: TImageList;
begin
  ImageList:=TImageList.Create(Self);
  ImageList.Masked:=false;
  ImageList.ColorDepth:=cd32bit;
  pngbmp:=TPNGImage.Create;
  pngbmp.LoadFromFile('test.png');
  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  pngbmp.AssignTo(bmp);
  // ====================================================
  // Important or else it gets alpha blended into the list! After Assign
  // AlphaFormat is afDefined which is OK if you want to draw 32 bit bmp
  // with alpha blending on a canvas but not OK if you put it into
  // ImageList -- it will be way too dark!
  // ====================================================
  bmp.AlphaFormat:=afIgnored;
  ImageList_Add(ImageList.Handle, bmp.Handle, 0);
```

You must include

ImgList, PngImage

If you now try:

```
  Pngbmp.Draw(Bmp1.Canvas,Rect);
and
  ImageList.Draw(Bmp1.Canvas,0,0,0,true);
```

you'll see that the images are the same. Actually, there are a few
\pm 1 rgb differences due to rounding errors during alpha blending
but you cannot see them with naked eye. Neglecting to set
bmp.AlphaFormat:=afIgnored; would result in the second image being
much darker!

Best regards,

alex

Comment: Put CommCtrl to uses clause to make ImageList_Add() available.

Answer (score 2):

- Create an instance of TPngImage, PngImage: PngImage
- Load the image into this instance, PngImage.LoadFromFile(..)
- Create an instance of TBitmap, Bitmap: TBitmap
- Assign the PNG to the bitmap, Bitmap.Assign(PngImage)
- Add the bitmap to the image list
- Job done!