# Copying transparent (32bit alpha) bitmap from TImageList in ComboBox DrawItem event

Tags: delphi, c++builder, alpha-transparency, c++builder-2010

I am customizing OnDrawItem event to draw icons next to item names.
Here is my code so far for the event OnDrawItem:

```cpp
void __fastcall Form1::ComboBox1DrawItem(TWinControl *Control, int Index,
                                         TRect &Rect, TOwnerDrawState State)
{
TComboBox* CB = static_cast<TComboBox*>(Control);
CB->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);

boost::scoped_ptr<Graphics::TBitmap> bitmap(new Graphics::TBitmap());
bitmap->PixelFormat = pf32bit;
bitmap->AlphaFormat = afPremultiplied;

ImageList1->GetBitmap(Index, bitmap.get());

bitmap->AlphaFormat = afPremultiplied;

if (bitmap->Canvas->Handle)
    {
    // structure for alpha blending
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
    bf.BlendOp              = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags           = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha  = 0xFF;         // 0x00 (transparent) through 0xFF (opaque)
    bf.AlphaFormat          = AC_SRC_ALPHA; // Use bitmap alpha

    ::AlphaBlend(CB->Canvas->Handle,    // handle to destination DC
             Rect.Left + 2,             // x-coord of upper-left corner
             Rect.Top,                  // y-coord of upper-left corner
             bitmap->Width,             // destination width
             bitmap->Height,            // destination height
             bitmap->Canvas->Handle,    // handle to source DC
             0,                         // x-coord of upper-left corner
             0,                         // y-coord of upper-left corner
             bitmap->Width,             // source width
             bitmap->Height,            // source height
             bf                         // alpha-blending function
            );
    }

    Rect = Bounds(Rect.Left + 20 + 2, Rect.Top, Rect.Right - Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top);

    DrawTextW(CB->Canvas->Handle, CB->Items->Strings[Index].c_str(), -1, &Rect, DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
}
```

The problem of course is getting a transparent `TImageList1` to copy to transparent `TBitmap` preserving 32-bit alpha transparency/semi-transparency. Currently I get it out with white background in the resulting `TBitmap`.

Just to be clear, `TImageList` `ColorDepth` is set to `cd32bit` with `DrawingStyle = dsTransparent` before loading images to it and the images on it are transparent, no problems there.

What is the trick to solve this?

**UPDATE AND MY FINAL SOLUTION**

Based on a reply here here is my final working code for someone else who might need it in the future. This of course is just a template code which you might want to customize further to your own needs.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBox1DrawItem(TWinControl *Control, int Index, TRect &Rect, TOwnerDrawState State)
{
if (Index >= 0)
        {
        TComboBox* CB     = static_cast<TComboBox*>(Control);
        CB->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
        // Note - ImageList1 already has DrawingStyle set to dsTransparent          
        ImageList1->Draw(CB->Canvas, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top, 0);
        Rect = Bounds(Rect.Left + ImageList1->Width + 2 + 2, Rect.Top, Rect.Right - Rect.Left - ImageList1->Width - 2, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top);
        DrawTextW(CB->Canvas->Handle, CB->Items->Strings[Index].c_str(), -1, &Rect, DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you let the image list draw? You can use its draw method for that. Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352497/delphi-get-bitmap-from-a-timagelist .

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks, that worked great... if you make it into a form of answer I will be more than glad to accept it. Otherwise I will wait for a while and make the answer myself.

Comment: Done. But what in your mind is a more verbose answer please post that and I'll  delete mine. You're welcome.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The suggestion was enough for me to solve the problem, I've updated my own question with the solution so it may help someone else in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to try and grab the original bitmap from the imagelist because the imagelist itself knows how to draw honoring transparency information. You can use its `Draw` method for that.

Otherwise, an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13357267/243614) suggests that setting `AlphaFormat` to 'afIgnored' before calling `GetBitmap` should preserve transparency.