# Saving transparent (alpha channel) PNG from TImageList

Tags: delphi, png, c++builder, imagelist, timagelist

I have a `TImageList` which contains transparent icons (32bit, with alpha channel). What I want to do is to save individual icons based on image index as PNG file(s), while preserving alpha channel transparency. Using RAD Studio 2010 so it has `TPngImage` support, no need for third party libraries. Images are loaded into TImageList from PNG "sprite" image using the method here - [Add a png image to a imagelist in runtime using Delphi XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221597/add-a-png-image-to-a-imagelist-in-runtime-using-delphi-xe) - so the transparency is preserved upon loading. Now I need to save them out individually, in other words, extract individual images from sprite images which is already loaded into TImageList.

My code so far:

```
int imageindex = 123;
boost::scoped_ptr<TPngImage>         png(new TPngImage);
boost::scoped_ptr<Graphics::TBitmap> bmp(new Graphics::TBitmap);

MyImageList->GetBitmap(imageindex, bmp.get()); // Using GetBitmap to copy TImageList image into separate TBitmap

png->Assign(bmp.get()); // Assign that bitmap to TPngImage
png->SaveToFile("C:\\filename.png");
```

The above works but it saves with the white background (transparency is not preserved after saving). I am probably missing a simple step but can't figure it out.

Delphi code is also welcome, shouldn't be hard to translate.

Comment: Try `MyImageList->GetIcon(...)` and save the icon directly with the file extension .png

Comment: @KeremD, this is a wrong approach. Although icon will have transparency, it will not have standard PNG-file header, hence you will not be able to open this *png-icon* as a regular PNG-file. Even instance of `TPngImage` will fail with exception if you try to feed your *png-icon* to it. Simple setting extension like this: `MyIcon.png`, doesn't make icon *real* PNG-file.

Comment: @Dima Sure, monday morning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain PNG-image from `TImageList` where it was added. Code below allows you to do this!
Firstly, add `PngImage` to your `uses` clause.

```
procedure LoadPNGFromImageList(AImageList: TCustomImageList; AIndex: Integer; var ADestPNG: TPngImage);
const
  PixelsQuad = MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad) - 1;
type
  TRGBAArray = Array [0..PixelsQuad - 1] of TRGBQuad;
  PRGBAArray = ^TRGBAArray;
var
  ContentBmp: TBitmap;
  RowInOut: PRGBAArray;
  RowAlpha: PByteArray;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(AImageList) or (AIndex < 0) or
     (AIndex > AImageList.Count - 1) or not Assigned(ADestPNG)
  then
    Exit;

  ContentBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ContentBmp.SetSize(ADestPNG.Width, ADestPNG.Height);
    ContentBmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

    // Allocate zero alpha-channel
    for Y:=0 to ContentBmp.Height - 1 do
      begin
        RowInOut := ContentBmp.ScanLine[Y];
        for X:=0 to ContentBmp.Width - 1 do
          RowInOut[X].rgbReserved := 0;
      end;
    ContentBmp.AlphaFormat := afDefined;

    // Copy image
    AImageList.Draw(ContentBmp.Canvas, 0, 0, AIndex, true);

    // Now ContentBmp has premultiplied alpha value, but it will
    // make bitmap too dark after converting it to PNG. Setting
    // AlphaFormat property to afIgnored helps to unpremultiply
    // alpha value of each pixel in bitmap.
    ContentBmp.AlphaFormat := afIgnored;

    // Copy graphical data and alpha-channel values
    ADestPNG.Assign(ContentBmp);
    ADestPNG.CreateAlpha;
    for Y:=0 to ContentBmp.Height - 1 do
      begin
        RowInOut := ContentBmp.ScanLine[Y];
        RowAlpha := ADestPNG.AlphaScanline[Y];
        for X:=0 to ContentBmp.Width - 1 do
          RowAlpha[X] := RowInOut[X].rgbReserved;
      end;
  finally
    ContentBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Look at the picture. It is depicts what will happen if we set or not set such line of code:

```
ContentBmp.AlphaFormat := afIgnored;
```

[image]
Figure 1 is a result of setting `afIgnored` and the second one figure is a result of *not* setting `afIgnored`, allowing to use previously set `afDefined`.

*Original image is an image named Figure 1*

Using of code above in application:

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DestPNG: TPngImage;
begin
  DestPNG := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    // Initialize PNG
    DestPNG.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA, 8, 60, 60);

    // Obtain PNG from image list
    LoadPNGFromImageList(ImageList1, 0, DestPNG);

    // Output PNG onto Canvas
    DestPNG.Draw(Canvas, Rect(0, 0, 60, 60));
    DestPNG.SaveToFile('C:\MyPNGIcon.png');
  finally
    DestPNG.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for great answer - it works well (after some minor tweaks)! Turns out the main problem is that `ADestPNG.Assign` does not copy the alpha channel information so it has to be created and copied manually like you already did.